# Solving 2nd Order non homogeneous differential equation using Wronskian when one solution is given

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

[image]> Solve by variation of parameters $x^2 y'' + 2xy' - 6y = 5x^4$ and given that $x^2$ is a solution of homogeneous equation.

> **Hint:** Find other fundamental solution using Wronsian.

**My Attempt**

[image: Here is my attempt]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please include the context of the problem in your question, as well as what you have tried and where you are getting stuck exactly, so we may guide you properly. Thank you.

Comment: Mate, I have uploaded my answer for the question above. I need to make sure whether that is the right answer. Could you please tell me whether that is the final answer for the given question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean what does Y in my final answer mean? If I am not mistaken it is the second solution of the complementary function. Then how can we find the paticular function? From my previous attempts at ode solving I think the the answer to the given should be the combination of complimentary function and the paticular function.. Am I correct?

Comment: It would help if you put your image link in a chronological place and labeled it according to its contents. Even better would be if you communicated its contents as text+mathjax.

Comment: Youur last solution only solve the homogeneous equation now you hav to solbe th inhomoheneous DE.

Comment: I have added my latest solution. Could you please take a quick look and let me know whether this time I've got it right or not. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Given $y_1=x^2$ is a solution, you can reduce the order by substituting $y(x)=x^2v(x)$ to make it easier to find the other fundamental solution.

$$y=x^2v \implies y' = 2xv + x^2v' \implies y'' = 2v + 4xv'+ x^2v''$$

$$\begin{align*}
0 &= x^2y'' + 2xy' - 6y \\[1ex]
&= x^2(2v+4xv'+x^2v'') + 2x(2xv+x^2v') -6x^2v \\[1ex]
&= 6x^3v'+x^4v'' \\[1ex]
&= xw' + 6w & w(x)=v'(x)
\end{align*}$$

Solve for $w\to v\to y$.

$$\begin{align*}
w(x) &= Cx^{-6} \\
v(x) &= C_1x^{-5} + C_2 \\
y(x) &= C_1x^{-3} + C_2x^2
\end{align*}$$

The solution $y_1=x^2$ is already accounted for, so the other is $y_2=x^{-3}$.

Now the Wronskian is

$$W(y_1,y_2) = \begin{vmatrix} y_1 & y_2 \\ {y_1}' & {y_2}' \end{vmatrix} = -5x^{-2}$$

and you can proceed with variation of parameters.